# Objective-C : Changing "self" value inside self

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, categories, self

I have a category on NSDate, and I want to implement some functions to manipulate the date, like :

```
NSDate *thedate = [NSDate date];
[thedate setToMidnight];
```

so I have a function in NSDate like :

```
-(void)setToMidnight {
   some code with calendars and comps

   self = theNewDate;
}
```

This works inside the function, but outside this member function, thedate has not changed.
I understand this malfunction because I've been told that self is just a local variable created inside the member function.
So, how can I make this work ?

Of course, I could have written :

```
thedate = [thedate dateAsMidnightDate]
or thedate = [NSDate dateAtMidnightFromDate:thedate]
```

but I feel it has more sense inside the instance class, as I don't want to change the date but just adjust some values of the previously created one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Specifically:

1. A function or method cannot modify local variables in the calling context.
2. NSDate is not mutable (i.e. you can't modify an NSDate once it's created).

Therefore, no such method can be written. The closest you can get would be a class that wraps an NSDate and forwards messages to that internal NSDate object, which reassigns the date instance variable when you want to make it represent a new date.

Comment: Great... I will think about it but it seems to be just a little bit to complicated for that simple need. Is there a way to encapsulate a NSDate in a MyNSDate as you say, and route to the NSDate attribute the messages that are not implemented by MyNSDate ?

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, sorry, I should have explained a little bit better. That's what "forwards messages" refers to. Here's Apple's message forwarding guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

Comment: Great, great ! For now I have just made a category on NSDate but when I have some time, I will try this. Doing that way and implementing the forward message method into my class, do you know if the compiler will alert me (or will stop to alert me) when I send unsupported/forwarded messages to my class ?

Comment: @Chuck : I tried. The compiler does not like message forwarding :-) Many warnings raised.

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, that is true. You'll need to either declare any variable pointing to that class to be of type "id" or copy the declaration of all the original class's methods from its header.

Comment: @Chuck : I will probably need to deal with (id) because once I had declare a function in the header and not in the .m and the compiler didn't like it. This may be also the case here... Something to test.